# Umbraco - How to loop through content of a content saved event

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, events, umbraco

How do I get a list of the content of a page to loop through? I have a document type with an image picker and I want to check the width of my image with a Saving or Publishing event (doesn't really matters at this point)

```
private void ContentServiceSaved(IContentService sender, SaveEventArgs<IContent> e)
{
    foreach (var node in e.SavedEntities)
    {
        if (node.ContentType.Alias == "productDetail")
        {
            //Need foreach to loop through node's content
            //This forloop is the one I used in a media saving event, but I need to do this
            //with the image picker of my document before it gets published or maybe saved
            //----------------
            foreach (var mediaItem in e.SavedEntities)
            {
                //if it's an image, the content type will tell you.
                if (mediaItem.ContentType.Alias == "Image")
                {
                    var width = Convert.ToDouble(mediaItem.Properties["umbracoWidth"].Value);
                    var height = Convert.ToDouble(mediaItem.Properties["umbracoHeight"].Value);

                    if (height / width != 1)
                    {
                        //Sending a message will cancel the process, so you don't
                        //need an else (unless you want to do something else with the image of course.
                        string msg = "Ratio is not 1:1. Please make sure the width and height of your image is the same.";
                        e.DisposeIfDisposable();
                        e.CancelOperation(new EventMessage("Wrong Ratio", msg, EventMessageType.Error));
                        e.Messages.Add(new EventMessage("Wrong Ratio", msg, EventMessageType.Error));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            //----------------
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is with the foreach (var mediaItem in e.SavedEntities). This line of code is purely to explain my point, what I would need is something like (var mediaItem in node.Children) . I need the get the image of the imagePicker inside my page "productDetail" (node)

Comment: take a look at this from matt brailsford: https://gist.github.com/mattbrailsford/7eb24abe61a4c896b3e5
it might help you out